# Highlight the Search Keyword in the Result using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight results in my application like Google does it for their search.

How do I replace the anchor tag value with some html formatting?

**HTML and JavaScript Code:**

```
function createHtmlForCasting(response, key) {
    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
        var div = document.createElement("span");
        div.innerHTML = value.EventTitle;
        var arr = new Array();
        var div = document.createElement("span");
        div.innerHTML = value.EventTitle;
        var arr = new Array();
        arr = key.split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (div.innerHTML.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1) {
                div.innerHTML.replace(arr[i], "<b>" + arr[i] + "</b>")
            }
        }
    }
    }
$("#DivCasting").append("<a href='" + SiteUrl + "Job/" + value.EventID + "/" + CastingTitle + "' ><span>" + div.innerHTML + "</a></span>");
```

Comment: Also you're creating a new array in the variable `arr` twice.

Comment: Instead of implementing the highlighting yourself, you could use a JavaScript library. I used the open-source library [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) to implement the highlighting you can see on [Cogeco On Demand’s search page](http://www.cogecoondemand.com/search?q=work). If that plugin doesn’t work for you, try [this list of jQuery highlighting plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Here is HTML Body Text:**

> I want like google search highlight the search keywords in results in
>   my application using javascript.. how to using replace the anchor tag
>   value with some html formatting..

and we want to highlight '**using**' word then, you can try this with jQuery;

```
$(function () {   
   var textToReplace =  $('body').html();
    textToReplace = textToReplace.replace(/using/g,'<strong>using</strong>');
    $('body').html(textToReplace);
});
```

It will give you output like this:

> I want like google search highlight the search keywords in results in
>   my application **using** javascript.. how to **using** replace the anchor tag
>   value with some html formatting..